# Chart symbology not drawing?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, symbology, chart

I am trying to symbolize some polygons with charts, 3 columns each, from the attribute table that has all the fields and rows populated. I have checked for exclusions and queries and there are none. I am only using some simple vbscript for labels but that should not have any effect as it had not in previous maps that I created using the same shapefile only different fields. According to this the problem should be caused by the fields but on the other hand that should also prevent other charts from drawing...

Any ideas?

I am using ArcMap 10.2.2 for desktop.

[image]